# ApacheCommons: Weird results from ChiSquareTest

Tags: java, apache-commons, chi-squared

I am using the [Apache Commons lib](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/inference/ChiSquareTest.html) to calculate the p-value with the ChiSquareTest:

I use the method chiSquareTest(double[] expected, long[] observed); But the values I get back don't make sense to me. So I tried numerous ChiSquare Online Calculators to find out what this function calculates.

An example:

- Group 1: {25,25}
- Group 2: {30,20}
- (Taken from Wikipedia, German Chi Square Test article)

P- values from: 
http://www.quantpsy.org/chisq/chisq.htm and
http://vassarstats.net/newcs.html

```
P = 0.3149 and 0.31490284
0.42154642 and 0.4201
(with and without Yates Correction)


Apache Commons: 0.1489146731787664
```

Code:

```
ChiSquareTest tester = new ChiSquareTest();

long[] b = {25,25};
double[] a = {30,20};

tester.chiSquareTest(a,b);
```

Another thing I do not understand is the need to have a long and a double array. Why not two long arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two functions in the lib:

- chiSquareTest(double[] expected, long[] observed)
- chiSquareTest(long[][] values)

The first one (which I used in the question above) computes the goodness of a fit. But I expected the result from the second one, the test of independence.

The answer was given to me on the Apache Commons user Mailinglist, I will add a link to the archive once it is there. But it is also written in the JavaDoc.

Update:
[Mailinglist Archive](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-user/201512.mbox/%3CCAJSjvwt-axsfgjYFM=6nm1kh6iqObgPE4L5Uo1GEGNOtJsnzGQ@mail.gmail.com%3E)